# Find ARRAY by to its values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array like so:

```
$a = array(
  'potatoe'=> array(
      'weight'=>24,
      'label'=>'kon',
      'year'=>2001,

   ),

  'apple'=> array(
      'weight'=>55,
      'label'=>'krakat',
      'year'=>1992,
   )
);
```

I am looking for a way to searching the fruit name (with its values) when I only know weight is `55` and year is `1992`. How to do that?

Comment: A Simple foreach loop?!

Comment: i was interested if there is like  `array_search` or etc

Comment: No, PHP does provide you with functions like `hammer()` or `screwdriver()`, but it does NOT provide a function for ever thing you want to do like `build_me_a_pink_house()`. But you can of course build your pink house with a hammer and a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to iterate over it using foreach and test every element.

```
function findFruit($array,$weight, $year){
    foreach($array as $key => $fruit){
        if($fruit['weight'] == $weight && $fruit['year'] == $year ){
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

then, just use the function:

```
$theFruit = $a[findFruit($a,55,1992)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['weight'] == 55 && $value['year'] == 1992) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
apple
```

Comment: You missed to use `==`

Comment: sometimes `===` even better, when comparing same types correctly (string to string, int to int)